# Get Full Path of current photo in Fotorama With data-auto set to true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, photo-gallery, fotorama

I am using the fotorama version 4.5.2 plugin for a photo gallery on a personal website.  I want to be able to have a button on the page that will allow me to edit certain information about the current photo displayed that is stored in a database.  For this, I need some data about the current photo that is displayed, preferably the full path of the picture, but something like id would probably work.  My question is: How do I get this data about the current picture displayed?  I have seen some stuff where you can set data-auto to false and manually load fotorama.  I would prefer to leave the auto function set to true as I am happy with how everything is working, and it seems like too much of a hassle to set everything manually.  If the only way to get this data is by setting data-auto to false, then how do I set everything up manually?  I've found the API documentation on fotorama's site (http://fotorama.io/customize/api/) to be confusing, and my attempts to get it to work manually have failed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution. You can call this javascript function from a button and it will give you the current photo's full path.

```
function getPicName () {
    var name = $(".fotorama__active").find("img.fotorama__img").attr('src');
    alert(name);
}
```